# Detecting StackExchanges with non-standard "plugins" (e.g. MathJax)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Some recent StackExchanges are starting to include site specific 3rd party JavaScripts - for example, cstheory.stackexchange.com (and math.stackexchange.com) both use what I think is MathJax to render the mathematics. Users of these sites depend on features provided by these "SE plugins", so I'd like to replicate the functionality in [SixToEight](http://sixtoeightapp.com).

Alas, including MathJax in every site is expensive - the processing it does can be quite intensive, and the poor old iPhone 3G can hardly cope at the best of times. I'd like to include the needed JavaScript only on StackExchanges that use it, but I can't find a way of identifying these sites (short of hard-coding a list, or nasty analysis of the live HTML).

This problem boils down to two questions.

1. Are there other "plugins" used by
   other StackExchanges that I'm not
   aware of, that change the content
   display in a significant way?
2. Is it
   worth adding a list of these
   "plugins" to StackAuth, so we can
   include them only when necessary
   (and, if needed, disable Stack
   Exchanges with content we cannot
   support)?

With MathJax, it's not *strictly* necessary to have the plugin to view the content - the ASCII content is reasonably readable. It's just significantly suboptimal, and I'm worried that future sites will have other content that really is broken without 3rd party JavaScript.

Comment: i like the idea but it will most certainly (and understandably) be declined.

Comment: why understandably? Hopefully it will be accepted.

Comment: jonathan - you should preface directed responses with @sky (or @foo - at least three letters in the respondee's name) so that the respondee gets notification. As far as the feature - this would, amongst other things, tie the implementation to the meta data as well as adding a burden to the maintainers to keep this information up to date. It will certainly be declined. sorry. consolation prize is an upvote. ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a tricky one, and I can't really say how it will be solved in the future but we'll have to figure out something.

The inability to render questions is kind of a major deficiency (if one that didn't exist until well after 1.0 was frozen).

---

This has been added in 1.1.

`/1.1/sites` reports `markdown_extensions` with values `Prettify`, `MathJax`, and `jTab` as possible returns.  However, new extension can be added at any time.

Answer (score 1):

MathJax sites as of May 7 2012:

```
http://stats.stackexchange.com
http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com
http://math.stackexchange.com
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com
http://cstheory.stackexchange.com
http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com
http://electronics.stackexchange.com
http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com
http://physics.stackexchange.com
http://quant.stackexchange.com
http://meta.quant.stackexchange.com
http://crypto.stackexchange.com
http://dsp.stackexchange.com
http://sc.com
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com
http://cogsci.stackexchange.com
http://cs.stackexchange.com
http://chemistry.stackexchange.com
```

Comment: Wow... I didn't realize so many sites had deployed MathJax.

Comment: @George yeah, neither did I.. Until I needed to find out for this script: http://stackapps.com/questions/3373/mathjax-buttons