# Can StackAuth please report which sites use MathJax?

Tags: feature-request, stackauth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting StackExchanges with non-standard “plugins” (e.g. MathJax)](https://stackapps.com/questions/1646/detecting-stackexchanges-with-non-standard-plugins-e-g-mathjax)

I just added MathJax support to StackMobile (it seems to actually work on Android phones).

However, embedding MathJax on *every* single page seems like a waste. It would be nice to know which sites use MathJax and which ones don't.

Can StackAuth please include that information?

Comment: See my previous question http://stackapps.com/questions/1646/detecting-stackexchanges-with-non-standard-plugins-e-g-mathjax