# Markdown Shortcuts for StackExchange - insert latex commands quickly by keybindings

Tags: script, editing, markdown, keyboard-shortcuts

### About

This userscript gives users quick key bindings to speed up the process of editing mathjax/chem/etc. into posts.

**Example usage**:

1. Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> would insert `\pi` directly.
2. Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> would insert `\mathrm{}` with the caret auto-placed in the middle. Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> again would *unwrap* the `\mathrm{}` back.
3. Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> with some `text` pre-selected would insert `\mathrm{text}`, retaining the selection on the text. Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> again would *unwrap* the `\mathrm{text}` back to `text`, retaining the selection on text.
4. Prepending <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to any of the above keybindings will auto-surround the insertion text with `$$` (or `\$` on some other SE sites)

Do note that the key bindings, hotkeys, and there number and insertions are all completely customizable (absolutely nothing is hardcoded!) So, you can set it to insert `\pi` on <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> instead, or `\ice` on <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> instead.

Moreover, there are certain built-in keycodes like:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> => dollar-ifying (`text` => `$text$`)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> => double dollar-ifying (`text` => `$$text$$`)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> => frac-ify (`A/B` => `\frac{A}{B}`)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> => align-ify ([image demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmWFQ.png))

This also supports the pipe operator to place caret at a user-defined position. Read more on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/GaurangTandon/MarkdownShortcutsForSE).

**This userscript is easily extensible**. If your site wants some custom functions to be implemented, please let me know below.

### **[Install link](https://github.com/GaurangTandon/MarkdownShortcutsForSE/raw/master/MarkdownShortcutsSE.user.js)**

And [view source](https://github.com/GaurangTandon/MarkdownShortcutsForSE/blob/master/MarkdownShortcutsSE.user.js).

---

#### List of default LaTeX commands

```
Keycode Command
Alt-I   \pi
Alt-R   \mathrm{}
Alt-E   \ce{}
Alt-W   \pu{}
Alt-T   \text{}

Alt-Z   dollarify
Alt-C   double dollarify
Alt-S   frac-ify
Alt-A   align-ify
```

---

#### Note

This userscript expands the featureset of the [previous userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/3373/mathjax-buttons) and has been built from the ground up - six years later!

#### License

Do whatever you wish to do, just don't sell this for money (but may use it in a commercial software's code) or state that you made it yourself. Do post here an answer if you do something cool with this :D

#### Contribute

Post bugs or feature requests as answers below!